# How to batch update multiple workitems in TFS

Tags: api, tfs, powershell, bug-tracking

I need to update same field to same value for hundreds of workitems in TFS. Is there any way to do it in a batch instead of updating them manually one by one?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can do this in **Excel**:

1. Open the work items in Excel, via:

   - right click a query in Team Explorer -> open in Excel
   - multi-select some work items in a WIT result pane, then right click -> open in Excel
   - load Excel, use Team -> Import to load a predefined query
   - open a *.xls file that is already bound to TFS
2. Make your bulk edits
3. Click the Publish button on the Team ribbon

[image]

Full documentation:
[Managing work items in Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286627(VS.100).aspx) (overview page; lots & lots of links inside)

[You can bulk-edit in the web interface too](http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/archive/2007/11/06/tswa-tip-bulk-edit.aspx)

**Windows command line**:

```
REM make Martin Woodward fix all my bugs
tfpt query /format:id "TeamProject\public\My Work Items" | 
    tfpt workitem /update @ /fields:"Assigned To=Martin"
```

**Powershell**:

```
# make Bill & Steve happy
$tfs = tfserver -path . -all
$items = $tfs.wit.Query("
    SELECT id FROM workitems 
    WHERE [Created By] IN ('bill gates', 'steve ballmer')") | 
    % {
        $_.Open()
        $_.Fields["priority"].value = 1
        $_
    }
# note: this will be much faster than tfpt since it's only one server call
$tfs.wit.BatchSave($items)
```

Comment: And powershell?  (I know you want to dazzle with your l33t powershell skilz again :-) )

Comment: just curious: Is it possible to attach the same file to multiple tfs workitems... either using web interface or powershell?

Comment: I want to update test case status that is pass or fail via excel..is it possible to do that?

Comment: @RichardBerg can you show an example changing the 'Automated Test Name' and 'Automated Status'?  I get an error because the 'Automated Status' needs to go from planned to automated... but automated is not in the list of values.

Answer (score 0):

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $TfsPasswd -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($TfsUserName, $secpasswd)
Connect-TfsTeamProjectCollection -Server $TfsServerUrl -Collection $TfsCollection -Credential $mycreds
#Get-TfsTeamProject

Connect-TfsTeamProject -Project $TfsProjectName
$workItems  = Get-TfsWorkItem -Filter "[System.WorkItemType] = 'Bug' AND [System.AssignedTo] = '$TfsUserName'"
foreach ($workItem in $workItems)
{
    $tpc = $workItem.Store.TeamProjectCollection
    $id = $workItem.Id
    $store = $tpc.GetService([type]'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore')
    $wi = $store.GetWorkItem($id)
    $projectName = $wi.Project.Name
    foreach($fldName in $Fields.Keys)
    {
        $wi.Fields[$fldName].Value = $Fields[$fldName]
    }
    $wi.Save()
}
```

You can download detail script from [how to batch update multiple work items in TFS by PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-batch-update-149046f5)