# Missing work items on Kanban board after team change

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfs-workitem, workitem

Good morning,

after some problem with my project team configuration I decided to create a new team and delete the old one. At this point I'm not able to see work items on the Kanban Boards but only on "Work Items" menu.
How to restore all the work items on Kanban board?

This is the actual situation

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Missing work items on Kanban board after team change

That because you created a new team, it has a default **`Area path`**. This default **`Area path`** is different from the default **`Area path`** of your old team. Therefore, the **`Area path`** of the workitems you created on the old team are the default **`Area path`** of the old team, and it will not be displayed in the new team's broads. This is the cause of your issue.

To resolve this issue, we could change the area path of the workitems:

[image]

[image]

You could refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210571/how-to-batch-update-multiple-workitems-in-tfs) to batch update multiple workitems.

**Besides**, we could use another way to resolve this issue, we could change the default area path for the new team:

[image]

Hope this helps.